# Constructor and destructor in multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, raii

when I try to use `mutex` with RAII.

```
class MutexLock
{
public:
    MutexLock() {
        pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);
        cout << "construct of MutexLock" << endl;
    }
    ~MutexLock() {
        cout << "deconstruct of MutexLock" << endl;
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);
    }

    void lock() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    }

    void unlock() {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
    }

private:
    MutexLock(const MutexLock &);
    MutexLock& operator=(const MutexLock &); 

    pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
};

class MutexLockGuard
{
public:
    explicit MutexLockGuard(MutexLock &mutex): mutex_(mutex) {
        cout << "construct of MutexLockGuard" << endl;
        mutex_.lock();
    }
    ~MutexLockGuard() {
        cout << "deconstruct of MutexLockGuard" << endl;
        mutex_.unlock();
    }

private:
    MutexLockGuard(const MutexLock &);
    MutexLockGuard& operator=(const MutexLock &);
    MutexLock &mutex_;
};


MutexLock mutex;
int cnt = 5;

void *f(void *arg){
    long t_num = (long) arg;
    while(true){
        MutexLockGuard lock(mutex);
        if(cnt>0){
            usleep(1);
            cout << "args: " << t_num << " " << "cnt: " << cnt-- << endl; 
        } 
        else{break;}       
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid, tid1, tid2, tid3;
    int ret = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, f,(void*)11);
    if(ret == -1){
        perror("create error\n");
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, f, (void*)22);
    if(ret == -1){
        perror("create error\n");
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, f, (void*)33);
    if(ret == -1){
        perror("create error\n");
    }

    ret = pthread_create(&tid3, NULL, f, (void*)44);
    if(ret == -1){
        perror("create error\n");
    }

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid3, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The result shows as

```
construct of MutexLock
construct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
args: 11 cnt: 5
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
args: 11 cnt: 4
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
args: 11 cnt: 3
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
args: 11 cnt: 2
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
args: 11 cnt: 1
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
construct of MutexLockGuard
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
deconstruct of MutexLockGuard
deconstruct of MutexLock
```

When the four threads are created, four instances of `MutexLockGuard` are created. But why is the thread `args: 11` destructed while the lifetime of other three threads are as long as the main thread?

Comment: What is your question? "I don't understand" is not a question. Spend more time understanding it, then come to us with a question. We are not a mentoring or teaching service; this is a professional Q&A!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: inb4 yes I am aware of the irony of the repeated exclamation marks

Answer (score 1):

Your code is creating four threads.

Each of those threads enters the `while(true)` loop in `f()`, and therefore creates a `MutexLockGuard`.   Then one of the threads enters the mutex, and execution continues.

So the sequence is

1)   Four threads started, and all four create a `MutexLockGuard`.   Hence the four lines `construct of MutexLockGuard`.

2)   One of the threads (the first created according to your output) succeeds in locking the mutex, and produces the output `args: 11 cnt: 5`.

What this demonstrates is that locking a mutex is not necessarily instantaneous.   The main() thread is possibly creating all threads before it gets preempted by any of its child threads.

Answer (score 1):

All the threads construct a `MutexLockGuard` but only one is permitted to acquire the mutex and proceed (as intended).

However, when that one destroys its `MutexLockGuard` and releases the mutex, it turns out that it loops around and creates a new `MutexLockGuard` and acquires the mutex before the system unblocks another thread and allows them to acquire the mutex.

Mutex acquisition is not guaranteed to be fair.  The system may act like this in an attempt to prevent spending work switching threads.

The moral of the story is to be careful not to assume that mutexes will order things.  All that you should assume mutexes will do is prevent threads from executing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when the thread is sleeping, it still holds the mutex. It only unlocks the mutex after it wakes up. So other threads do not have chance to get the mutex. Change the code as follow and try again

```
while(true){    
    if(cnt>0){
        usleep(1);
        {MutexLockGuard lock(mutex);
        cout << "args: " << t_num << " " << "cnt: " << cnt-- << endl; 
        }
    } 

    else{break;}       
}
```